# Is it a good practice to initialize a variable with "null" in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Which one makes more sense

```
var myVar = null;

myVar = someLogic(); //someLogic() might return a primitive or an object

if(myVar){
  //other logic
}
```

OR

```
var myVar;

myVar = someLogic(); //someLogic() might return a primitive or an object

if(myVar){
  //other logic
}
```

Comment: There's no point in initializing a variable other than to set it to a value you want it to have.

Comment: They are not the same. The second case, myVar is set to undefined, not null.

Comment: Why did you think it might be best practice to initialize it to `null`?

Comment: It's irrelevant for JS. JS is prepared to work with nulls and undefineds without any problem. For logicals purposes both are "FALSE".

Comment: The best practice clearly would be `var myVar = someLogic();`

Comment: If you assign the variable before you use it, it makes no difference whether you initialized it when you declared it.

Comment: @Bergi,  that doesn't always work - e.g. I want to set a value in the callback of a promise and not declare it there.  This will enable the other callback functions further in the promise chain to see the updated value of this variable.

Comment: @torazaburo, I did not think it was a best practice. I "asked" whether it was.

Comment: @JosephYoung - the question was not whether they are same. The question was whether one has any advantage/disadvantage over other.

Comment: @Tintin: You really [should not do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28250700/1048572). There are much better ways to pass values between promise callbacks.

Comment: @Bergi , thanks for the link! Great answers there.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript, there is generally no good reason to initialize variables to `null`.

In languages like C, variables should always be initialized before use because there is no guarantee as to the value of an uninitialized variable – it could be 0, 1, 2, or 283942, or anything. However, JavaScript has no such problem. In JavaScript, variables that have been declared but not initialized will always have the value `undefined`.

`undefined` is it's own type in JavaScript. When cast to a boolean, it becomes `false`.

`undefined == null` returns `true`, but `undefined === null` returns `false`.

Semantically, `undefined` means that a value has not been set, whereas `null` means that there is no value, but we might expect one. However, there is no hard rule for this, as you can always assign the value `undefined` to a variable manually – I wouldn't recommend this.

In general, setting uninitialized variables to `null` would be a waste of time.